# Unshift the array on condition

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-7, php-5.3

I have written below lines of code

```
 public function shiftarray($cursor, $arg)
 {
     $keyarguments = array("first_name","roll_no");

     $arrayStudents =array();

       foreach ($cursor as $k => $row) 
       {
           foreach ($keyarguments as $key) 
            { 
                    if (strcasecmp($row[$key], $arg) == 0) 
                    {
                       array_unshift($arrayStudents, $row);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
               }  
         } 
      return $arrayStudents;                                     
 }
```

I have array of students in $cursor like

```
            { [0]=> array(50) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#23 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58131c7799fbad4c1d000202" } ["student_id"]=> float(2) ["registration_temp_perm_no"]=> string(1) "1" ["roll_no"]=> float(1) ["admission_date"]=> string(10) "01/07/2016" ["first_name"]=> string(7) "Neil" ["middle_name"]=> string(4) "David" ["last_name"]=> string(6) "Stephan" ["dob"]=> string(10) "12/03/1981" ["gender"]=> string(6) "Female" ["blood_group"]=> string(2) "A+" ["birth_place"]=> string(11) "Sadar Bazar" ["nationality"]=> string(6) "Indian" ["language"]=> string(7) "English" ["religion"]=> string(8) "Agnostic" ["address_line1"]=> string(20) "4148 Hazelcrest Hill" ["address_line2"]=> string(20) "22883 Memorial Place" ["city"]=> string(11) "Sadar Bazar" ["state"]=> string(13) "Uttar Pradesh" ["pincode"]=> string(6) "190010" ["country"]=> string(5) "India" ["phone1"]=> string(10) "9039180419" ["phone2"]=> string(10) "7681559402" ["email"]=> string(24) "educianstudent@gmail.com" ["is_sms_enabled"]=> string(3) "Yes" ["is_active"]=> int(1) ["has_finished"]=> int(0) ["student_category"]=> string(1) "5" ["course"]=> string(24) "58131c7099fbad4c1d0001c2" ["Biometric_ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["siblings"]=> string(14) "Cynthia Taylor" ["guardian_name"]=> string(14) "Cynthia Taylor" ["guardian_occupation"]=> string(13) "Senior Editor" ["guardian_qualification"]=> string(20) "Research Assistant I" ["guardian_email_id"]=> string(23) "educianparent@gmail.com" ["gaurdain_contact_details"]=> string(10) "9419513603" ["guardian_relationship"]=> string(6) "Father" ["height"]=> string(3) "4.9" ["weight"]=> string(4) "34.9" ["allergies"]=> string(0) "" ["batch"]=> int(2) ["academicyear"]=> string(4) "2015" ["batchhistory"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["batchid"]=> float(2) ["academic_year"]=> string(4) "2015" ["course"]=> string(24) "58131c7099fbad4c1d0001c2" ["sequenceno"]=> int(1) ["courseId"]=> object(MongoId)#24 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58131c7099fbad4c1d0001c2" } } } ["uploads"]=> array(1) { ["profile_pic"]=> string(39) "58131c7799fbad4c1d000202schoolgirl2.jpg" } ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> string(0) "" ["routearray"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["routeid"]=> int(2) ["academicyear"]=> string(4) "2016" ["current"]=> int(0) ["vehicleno"]=> string(9) "JK01S8764" ["dateofassignment"]=> string(10) "09/28/2016" } [1]=> array(5) { ["routeid"]=> int(3) ["academicyear"]=> string(4) "2016" ["current"]=> int(1) ["vehicleno"]=> string(9) "JK01S8764" ["dateofassignment"]=> string(10) "11/17/2016" } } ["HostelAlloted"]=> array(7) { ["Food Preferences"]=> string(4) "Both" ["Hostel"]=> object(MongoId)#25 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58138aee99fbade41e000031" } ["Floor"]=> string(7) "Floor_1" ["RoomNumber"]=> int(11) ["Approved"]=> string(3) "yes" ["Approved On"]=> object(MongoDate)#26 (2) { ["sec"]=> int(1472322600) ["usec"]=> int(0) } ["Academic Year"]=> string(4) "2016" } ["HostelAllotmentHistory"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["Food Preferences"]=> string(4) "Both" ["Hostel"]=> object(MongoId)#27 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58138aee99fbade41e000031" } ["Floor"]=> string(7) "Floor_1" ["RoomNumber"]=> int(11) ["Approved"]=> string(3) "yes" ["Approved On"]=> object(MongoDate)#28 (2) { ["sec"]=> int(1472322600) ["usec"]=> int(0) } ["Academic Year"]=> string(4) "2016" } } ["courseId"]=> object(MongoId)#29 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58131c7099fbad4c1d0001c2" } }
         ...
         ...
```

I am trying to bring those student on the beginning of array whose first name is brian  and rest of students should at the bottom.

Now the above code place the students on the top of the array but the rest of the students are ommited/removed. I don't want them to be removed.

I am trying to tweak what code to write in else condition.

Please help!!!

Comment: Anybody help me please !!!

Comment: Can you pls revise yer code to be one stand-alone case that can be executed as-is? Perhaps read sscce.org. Also can you include in that a test which demonstrates your expectations explicitly, eg: `$expectedValue = [1,2,3]; $actualValue=yourFunction();assert($expectedvalue == $actualValue);` Keep the example as small as possible to demonstrate the vagaries of what you require (say a coupla "Brians" and just a few "non-Brians", in an order to demonstrate the functionality "working"). We do not need all 50 records of example data in one unwrapped like of non-executable "code".

Comment: I have updated my question... Now the rest of data are removed... I don't want them to be removed... please help me!!!

Comment: "Can you pls revise yer code to be one stand-alone case that can be executed as-is". You have not done that. "Also can you include in that a test which demonstrates your expectations explicitly" nor have you done that.

Comment: I am not getting you

Answer (score 0):

Fill $arrayStudents before the loop otherwise only matches will be collected and unshifted.

Extend example of php.net/unshift

```
$add = array('big');

$queue = array(
    array("orange"),
    array("banana"),
    array("apple1"),
    array("raspberry")
);

array_unshift($queue, $add);
print_r($queue);
```

In your case: search for keys you want to unshift, the rest goes to the standard $list = array(/*list of studends*/):

```
$list = array();
$bringToTop = array('brian', 'elvis');
foreach($data as $item) {
    if (/* in in the list to bring on top*/) {
        $memory[] = $item;      
    } else {
        $list[] = $item;      
    }
}

foreach($memory as $item) {
   array_unshift($list, $item);
}
print_r($list);
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Add `$arrayStudents[] = $row;` to your else scope. Here is a [simple demo](https://eval.in/818306) to illustrate it.

When matches add the element to the result from the start of array, unmatches add them from the end of the array.